# Pass information through jQuery in Joomla error

Tags: jquery, joomla

my jquery code is throwing an error in joomla, it's supposed to take the text from a textbox and insert it at the end of the URL that has been specified after the button has been clicked.

```
JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);

var url = 'https://test.com/storefrontCommerce/search.do;jsessionid=CD66CBFCC5658D6C9327AA269764EBB2?searchType=keyword&keyword=';
$('button').click(function() {
      window.location.replace(url + $('#textbox').val());
});
```

Here is the error message I receive: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR in /home/dival/public_html/templates/proposed/index.php on line 35

This is from my index.php file in the template I'm using:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * Template for Joomla! CMS, created with Artisteer.
 * See readme.txt for more details on how to use the template.
 */

// load jQuery, if not loaded before
  if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
     JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
     $document = JFactory::getDocument();
     $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "templates/template_name/js/jquery.js");
  }

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'functions.php';

// Create alias for $this object reference:
$document = $this;

// Shortcut for template base url:
$templateUrl = $document->baseurl . '/templates/' . $document->template;

Artx::load("Artx_Page");

// Initialize $view:
$view = $this->artx = new ArtxPage($this);

// Decorate component with Artisteer style:
$view->componentWrapper();

JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');

var url = 'https://test.com/storefrontCommerce/search.do;jsessionid=CD66CBFCC5658D6C9327AA269764EBB2?searchType=keyword&keyword=';
$('button').click(function() {
      window.location.replace(url + $('#textbox').val());
});

?>
```

Comment: What error is being displayed? Also, I hope you realise that `JHtml...` is PHP and not jQuert code. Just making sure you do as you've put them in the same block of code here

Comment: I have edited original post to include the error message as well as a look at my index.php file from our template.

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely cringed when I saw `Artx::load`. Hope you had a good reason to go with an Artisteer template.

Anyway back on-topic. You have added you jQuery code inside  tags. This can't happen as they are 2 completely different languages. You can however use PHP (Joomla API methods in this case) to execute jQuery like so:

```
$js = " $('button').click(function() {
           var url = 'https://test.com/storefrontCommerce/search.do;jsessionid=CD66CBFCC5658D6C9327AA269764EBB2?searchType=keyword&keyword=';
           window.location.replace(url + $('#textbox').val());
        });
      ";
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document ->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Notice that I have also put thr `url` variable inside the click function as it's not a global variable.

Hope this helps